# CoreLocation: monitor only certain regions at a time

Tags: iphone, ios4, core-location, regions

In my iPhone app I'd like to monitor if the user enters some particular geographycal regions at a time and act consequently. 
I now saw that with the new iOS 4 it is possible to register some interest regions (CLRegion) to a CLLocationManager, so it would do some job for me, but... I'd also need to dynamically change the set of the regions (thus signaling the user only some region at some time) but it seems that Regions can only be added.
Before noticing this change in iOS 4 I was planning on using an R-Tree to index all the regions (as rectangles in a 2d space) and query it on demand obviously adding/removing nodes by myself.
Here are my questions:
- Anyone knows if the CLLocationManager uses something similar to an R-Tree?
- Is it extreamly efficient ? (I could put all my regions as registered at some point and the apply a filter such as looking in an NSSet of available-at-that-moment scenes)
- I'd like to delete, at least, all the monitored regions in the CL, is it feasible? How?

Comment: Have you successfully implemented region monitoring, monitoring only certain regions at a time, stopping and registering them on-the-fly? How many regions you are monitoring at a time? I'm working on a similar task for more than a week but still struggling. I'm also using significant change monitoring but I'm  getting a very inaccurate location results (horizontalAcccuracy might be as high as 8.5 km) when app is in background.

Comment: I have ~400 places that need to be monitored. There's no info about max number of monitored regions but I found 10 regions to be OK. Another problem I'm facing is about some "heavy" calculations that need to be done in order to loop though all places, find and register 10 closest, and also to track and mark visit times. So, I'm not sure how much time do I have for those calculation when the app is in background and receives didEnterRegion/didExitRegion/didUpdateToLocation callback. I have a suspicion there's a limit. Have you faced these problems too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with `-[CLLocationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:]`?

Comment: I feel like an idiot : D ty I totally missed that (maybe I got mislead by the fact that regions remain even between the application launches). Nevertheless, thank you.
Do you know something about the performance of this framework?